# Entering one address but get two locations with uneque locationId

Tags: here-api

Noticed a problem with geocoder api.
[https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey={apiKey}&in=countryCode%3ALTU&query=kreves%20pr.%2067](https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey=%7BapiKey%7D&in=countryCode%3ALTU&query=kreves%20pr.%2067)

top 2 results seem good but why 2 of them?
Addresson both of them seem identical but postalCodes are difirent and the one with 50355 doesn't even exists when I check in other places.
Maybe I need to do some filtering?

results:
[image]

Comment: Could you please include the results of your query here? Not everyone has a valid API key to perform the query.

Comment: Included results

Comment: Next time, please post any code or markup as text, as opposed to screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out why autocomplete api gave such results (same problem form most addresses) started using their lookup api instead (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-lookup-brief.html) seems to be working corectly.

Answer (score 0):

In Lithuania country many postal codes have very small areas therefore between those areas exist many borders as well. This address kreves pr. 67 LTU is on such border between pc 50355 and pc 50357. Of course perhaps pc 50355 doesn't exist in reality as well.

This is not Geocoder API issue but map core data issue.

For such issues please report on https://mapcreator.here.com/ . There you can edit map data as well.